# Jugendwort 2015

Tags: slang, teen-slang

Heute stand in der *Süddeutschen Zeitung* eine Glosse zur Wahl des *[Jugendwortes 2015](http://www.jugendwort.de/)*. Die Glosse legt nahe, dass die gelisteten Wörter, von denen mir einige ganz lustig und originell erscheinen, tatsächlich von Jugendlichen gar nicht verwendet werden. Ist das so?

Comment: während 2-3 wirklich ganz lustig sind, bin ich mir zu 100% sicher dass von diesen worten nur sehr wenige tatsächlich verwendung finden. augentinnitus und kompostieren z.b. sind uralt. gesichtspalmieren ist der peinliche versuche den begriff facepalm ins deutsche zu übersetzen usw.

Comment: @Alex: facepalm heißt unter ITlern schon länger *fazialpalmieren*. Es geht da vermutlich weniger um die korrekte Übersetzung als darum, dass es ein abstruser Begriff ist.

Comment: @Veredomon ist mir auch klar :) nur kommt es im Deutschen einfach nicht so rüber wie im Englischen, finde ich. Auch habe ich den Begriff im Deutschen noch nie gehört, schon gar nicht in Umgangssprache. Da sind die englischen Pendants beliebter. Ich arbeite selber in der IT Branche und hab die deutschen Versionen noch nie gehört :) Gott sei Dank!

Answer (score 3):

Um die Frage beantworten zu können, müsste man eine repräsentative Umfrage zu Rate ziehen. Vielleicht gibt es eine, keine Ahnung.

Ich bin mir aber, wie bereits in den Kommentaren geäußert, sehr sicher, dass von diesen Wörtern so gut wie keine genutzt werden. Gerade auf Social-Network-Plattformen ist relativ gut ersichtlich, welche Ausdrücke eher verwendet werden. Ich kenne selber genug „Junggebliebene“ und auch „Jugendliche“, die solche Wörter niemals in den Mund nehmen würden. Diese Art Listen stammen meistens von Leuten, die mit der eigentlichen Sache überhaupt gar nichts zu tun haben und demnach eine Aussagekraft wie die [Tipps der Bravo zum Flirten](http://www.vice.com/de/read/wir-haben-die-flirttipps-der-bravo-nach-gruseligkeit-geordnet-555) haben.

Auch wenn einige Begriffe sehr unterhaltsam sind, glaube ich nicht, dass sie von einer größeren Anzahl Jugendlichen genutzt werden. Wenn überhaupt.

Ich glaube eher, dass diese ganze „Lektüre“ zur Jugendsprache dazu dient, „witzige“ Umschreibungen festzuhalten, die aber niemand wirklich nutzt (eben zur Belustigung). Ich habe mal in einem Pons gelesen, dass „Entsafterin“ das neue Wort für „Freundin“ sei. In die gleiche Kategorie würde ich „Eierfeile“ und Co einordnen :) Also nicht zu Ernst nehmen!

Comment: `Earthporn` oder aber der weitaus geläufigere Begriff `Techporn` (Für nett anzusehende Technik, Bildern aus Rechenzentren, selbstgebaute Schaltkreise, ...) oder aber auch `Kabelporn` (Ein beispiel wiederum Rechenzentren wo dicke Bündel von LAN-Kabeln ordentlich verlegt sind) sieht man schon ab und an, allerdings eher Online. Ich bezweifle, dass das jemand im allgemeinen Sprachgebrauch nutzt.

Comment: `*porn` schon eher, earthporn aber ist aber nun wirklich selten. foodporn und scienceporn sind mir sehr geläufig, techporn auch schon wieder weniger